# box sit absolute on the bottom and if there is a content above the box will go down

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I have problem with css, I make html layout and need to get bluebox sit on the bottom above searchbox, and if there is a content above the bluebox then the bluebox will go down so there is a gap beetwen bluebox and content above. But if there is no content the bluebox will sit on the bottom above the searchbox.

you can see the html here:

http://projects.elixirbox.com/lanrex/test.html

you can see what I mean here - http://projects.elixirbox.com/lanrex/view.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a "sticky-footer" technique, using negative margins. The only down side you footer (or in your case Call to Action-box) need to have a fixed height.

If you need dynamic height you need to involve javascript. But use the same sticky-footer css with some default height and later just adjust it with JS so it's not just pure JS.

https://gist.github.com/1855032 
or
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I have try that and work well, thanks for share sticky footer :)

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are looking like this :-

```
.greybox {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightgrey;
    padding: 20px;
}

.bluecorner {
    background: url("../images/bg_blue_corner.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 315px;
}
```

And there is no need to define `position-absolute` to `.bluecorner` we can the get desired result as per your image normaly with margin-top....

**See the refereed image how i did the thing**......

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but if I remove the position-absolute and if I have less content above the bluebox will float above the searchbox and make gap there. you can see screenshot here - http://projects.elixirbox.com/lanrex/view2.png